# What's a good low-budget kayak for both river and sea?

Tags: kayaks

I'm looking to get a second-hand kayak, preferably under £250, which I can use for river kayaking and sea kayaking - is there a particular kind I should go for? I've done a bit of river and sea kayaking but am certainly no expert. Cheers!

Comment: What sort of rivers? And for that matter, shat sort of sea trips?

Comment: Without more details it is hard to give a good recommendation. Answers to Chris's comment are essential for this question to be answerable imo.

Comment: With more information along the lines asked for by Chris in his comment above, and some reworking, this Q can escape the dreaded "opinion based" stigma.  For example, "Under these conditions (which you specify a la Chris) , what are the most important features in a kayak  that I should I look for?  If I buy a second-hand kayak, which is probably all I can afford, are there potential problems I should ask about and be alert for when I examine it?"

Answer (score 3):

There's still a covid tax on most used sports equipment so there's no saying how much a good used boat will cost, however the class you're probably looking for are called crossover kayaks. The best known in the UK are the Wavesport Ethos, Dagger Katana and Pyranha Fusion.

They're all around 3m long, and have both a hatch and a skeg. In the grand scheme of things there's not much to choose between them, they're not perfect for any specific task but good enough for most.

The hatch means you can take enough kit for an overnight trip, the length means you can travel moderate distances while still being short enough for good maneuverability. They're also wide enough to be stable for a relative beginner.